# Compile LIB for CppSQLite3 class with visual studio

Tags: c++, sqlite

I try to use this class in visual studio 2013.

But function

```
CppSQLite3DB db_handle;
db_handle.open(name.c_str()); // this func returns error
```

returns:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CppSQLite3DB::open
```

I thought that was linker problem.

So i made sure and i have add added lib folder (with sqlite3.lib) and in visual studio i have add (in linker -> additional depedencies ) 'sqlite3.lib'

But problem is still not fixed.

I try to compile own 'lib' by :`lib /def:sqlite.def`

.lib file change own size (new size != old default lib size ) but problem not fixed.

And idea?

Comment: You add the sources files (.cpp) of CppSQLite3DB to your project or link with the .lib generated by this files?

Comment: Hmm i a litte do not understand question but i have in my class header `#include <CppSQLite3.h>` and i add folder with `CppSQLite3.h` `CppSQLite3.cpp` `sqlite3.h` in c/c++ > general > additional include directories

Comment: Add the CppSQLite3.cpp to your project and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Lol really its working ;0 Thanks :D But tell me why it wasn't work ?
I thought that all class like (string) etc. i dont have to add .cpp file to project

Comment: You include the declarations of the functions of CppSQLite3 but not the implementation and the linker don't find this and report the error. `std::string` is a typedef to a `generic class` (template), and this normally go in header files.